# Computation of boundedness and norm of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces, operator-theory

**Exercise**: Consider $C[0,1]$ with the sup-norm. Define $T : C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ as $$Tf(x) = \int_0^xf(t)dt.$$Show that $T$ is bounded and compute its norm.

**Attempt**:We start by showing $T$ is bounded. Notice that \begin{align*}||Tf||_\infty & = \max_{x \in [0,1]}|\int_0^xf(t)dt|\\
& \leq \max_{x \in [0,1]}|\max_{y \in [0,1]}|f(y)|\int_0^x|dt\\
& = \max_{y \in [0,1]}|f(y)|\max_{x \in [0,1]}|\int_0^xdt|\\
& = \max_{y \in [0,1]}|f(y)|\cdot 1.
\end{align*}Thus, $T$ is bounded and $||T|| \leq 1$. We show the reverse inequality. Notice that for $f(x) = 1$ for each $x \in [0,1]$ we have $||f||_\infty = \max_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)| = 1$, and so \begin{align*}||T|| & = \sup_{\substack{f \in C[0,1]\\||f||_\infty = 1}}||Tf||_\infty\\
& \geq \max_{x \in [0,1]}|\int_0^xdt|\\
& = 1.\end{align*}Thus, $||T|| = 1$.

**Question**: Can anyone check if my proof is correct?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: @Surb solution verification

Comment: Yes it's good. Few things : $\|Tf(x)\|_\infty $ doesn't mean anything, it should be $\|Tf\|_\infty $ (notice that $Tf(x)$ is a number, not a function). Moreover, The first part proved that $\|T\|\leq 1$, not that $\|T\|\geq 1$. The rest is fine :-)

Comment: @Surb Oh yeah indeed!! I will edit those typos! Thank you very much